# Test Data Strategy for integration testing Listing Pages

Tags: php, testing, integration-testing

My app are Listing Pages: e.g. Products/Categories from a store, List of Doctors in LA in a Directory or results of a search etc.

I am restructuring/refactoring/modernizing a legacy application and when starting, the only type of tests that I can write are integration tests e.g. using Selenium/equivalent to actually hit the page on server. Code that urgently needs refactoring includes extremely complex and bloated functions that handle filtering of lists. I need integration tests to ensure that code doesn't get broken by the refactoring. As refactoring progresses, I will slowly integrate unit tests.

I understand how to create integration test to say check that product page exists and that it has relevant data. I could have a number of predefined products as seed database data which will be reset before every test and refer to those products explicitly in test.

But, how do setup tests for some complex listing page - that filters products by price/custom attributes, doctors by specialty and city etc. + results are paginated? If I where to check this manually, I would need a **significant amount of test data** and spot check if the filters are behaving as expected and pagination is working. Obviously, I am trying to automate this process but I am struggling with how to link the tests with the test data.

Some of the approaches I am thinking of:

1. Set up the test data, record how results are currently displaying (before refactoring code), then hard code that in test.

   Disadvantages: Hard coding test expectations that depends on **larger amounts of test data** seems so so fragile! It would just take adding one record to db to skew up expected results from filter!
2. Extract the SQL used currently by code, run that SQL in test, and compare results with those from page.

   Advantages: Test will not break if record is added to database as long as sql query doesn't change.

   Disadvantages: Feels to complex.
3. Rethink if the filter pages need testing and which parts?
4. ...

Comment: For your filtering system, can you set up your filters so that you have two filter values for each type? That way you are checking that each type filter works, both individually and cumulatively. It is probably not important to check that every filter value works, if they are applied in the same way (equality test).

Comment: @halfer I can have multiple filters together - e.g. city + specialty. But I am not sure if this is what you meant. Can you please explain some more.

Comment: For city, use "London" and "Berlin" (even if you have many more/other values). For speciality, use "paediatric" and "heart" (even if you have many more/other values). Then test for (a) no filter, (b) one of each filter, (c) both filters together. In so doing you are checking your filter system works without testing each and every filter combination. The only reason why you might want to check specific filters you actually have is if they work on a different basis to the others e.g. they are not simple equality filters.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, different filters work differently e.g. they add extra tables to the sql and are processed in individual ways. What I understood from your approach was to keep test data to a minimum so that for each filter I am testing, the result set should only contain 1-2 results which sound much more maintainable. And no need to test pagination in conjunction with filter since that can be tested independently.